# Why is this object type changing on me

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the dev tools it shows be the following type:

```
IClass {Class23}
```

In the debugger (while running) it shows it as the following type:

```
Class23
```

`IClass` and `Class23` have different properties, and it seems like I can access it while it's running as the type, but it doesn't build when I try to code properties for `Class23` because intellisense wants me to enter properties for `IClass`.  Can someone explain this behavior and how I am supposed to access the properties from `Class23` when the object is `IClass {Class23}`?

I tried this but it just returns null:

```
Class23 myclass = Function(returns IClass {Class23}) as Class23
```

Help!

---

Some code, not sure if it helps:

```
   Bucket Cats = Dictionary1["key1"] as Bucket;
   IEnumerable<IClass> links = Cats.Links;

   // this should actually be `Class23`
   var Name = links.ElementAt(0).Name; //<--Error
```

Comment: I think it will help, if you post a more complete version of your code.

Comment: Can you be very clear about what language you are using, and how `Class23` and `IClass` are declared? I'm *guessing* `public interface IClass {...}` and `public class Class23 : IClass {...}` - but...? Also: the parameter, local or field that you are talking about: how is **that** declared? as an `IClass`? or as a `Class23` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes IClass is an Interface class

Comment: @ZeeTee I asked a lot more than just one question ;p

Comment: Lol it's an interface, the other one is a class. I'm 1 month learning, please bear with me

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: `Interface IEnumerable<out T>` and IClass is `IEnumerable<IClass>`

Comment: Come on, you have enough rep to know how to make a question answerable. Please edit your question with enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @PatrickHofman There are so many variables and so many properties and types It'll take a day to prepare it

Comment: Just strip it to the useful stuff. Class layout, interface layout, method signature and the actual call.

Comment: I put the statement causing problems, not sure if it helps

Comment: @ZeeTee yes, that helps; I'll edit my answer to illustrate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the update:

```
IEnumerable<IClass> links = Cats.Links;

// this should actually be `Class23`
var Name = links.ElementAt(0).Name; //<--Error
```

The error here is your expectation. If you have a sequence of `IClass`, then `ElementAt(0)` **returns an `IClass`**. You don't get automatic casting (unless you cheat, and: don't). If you know that item is a `Class23`, then:

```
var Name = ((Class23)links.ElementAt(0)).Name; // could also use .First()
```

You could also potentially use:

```
IEnumerable<Class23> links = Cats.Links.Cast<Class23>();
```

however, frankly, I don't think you should be looking inside the interface *at all*. If it is useful for `IClass` to expose the `Name`, then *add `Name` to the `interface`*.

---

> In the dev tools it shows be the following type:

It *sounds* like the "it" you are referring to is statically typed as an `IClass`, and has been provided an instance of `Class23` which happens to implement `IClass`. That's fine and normal - nothing wrong there (except the names). But the entire point of interfaces is that you *shouldn't* normally need to talk to the type's members : you should only need the API exposed via the interface. If you need more: you have broken the abstraction. Sometimes, however, yes - you *need* to break the abstraction, for example to special-case some aspect. In which case... cast:

```
IClass foo = ...


if(foo is Class23) {
    var bar = (Class23)foo;
    bar.SomeClassMember = 42;
}
```

Comment: Just small addition. If you don't want break abstraction you can add Name property to Interface (interfaces can containt properties) Do this only if adding it seems reasonable from the point of all classes that implement interface.

Comment: @user2184057 so, a bit like where I say "however, frankly, I don't think you should be looking inside the interface at all. If it is useful for IClass to expose the Name, then add Name to the interface."